# A good 2D-primitive rendering library for C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, 2d, diagram

I'm developing a C#/.NET application (Winforms/WPF, not entirely decided yet) which needs to display simple diagrams: boxes/"text boxes", lines/arrows, circles, text etc... 
 Some items on the diagram need to be clickable/selectable, allowing me to display e.g. a dialog for filling in data on the selected item. 
 I guess the diagram display could all be done from scratch using e.g. GDI+, but before going down that path I would like to ask for input/suggestions on existing libraries to use (commercial or free)?

I've already tried to google for suitable libraries, but found mostly 2D game-engines or "graph/chart"-rendering libraries. Neither seem to fit my requirements.

Best regards,

Søren

Comment: @Arthur: Uhh, the diagrams need to be modifiable at runtime. Mayby I'm missing your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you said you looked already into "graph/chart" libraries. What about [Nevron Diagram](http://nevron.com/Products.DiagramFor.NET.Overview.aspx)? The only drawback would be that it is not free, but it doesn't cost that much.

Comment: That might be worth a try, seems to support everything I need. Perhaps a simpler library would do? Thanks for the tip, anyway (+1)

Comment: I'm still not entirely convinced that I will use "Nevron Diagrams" in my final product, but your response came the closests to meeting my requirements....

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Piccolo2D](http://www.piccolo2d.org/download.html) for Java, but they aslo have a .Net version, and it's community driven.

The only problem is, I don't know how updated the .Net version is or give any comment on how well it works (.Net version).

Comment: I would prefer a native C# library. What's the performance like for Piccolo2D?

Comment: Piccolo2d is what you are looking for. You can also check out the .net examples. I am not sure about the performance in .net, but the Java performance is fine.

Comment: We use Piccolo2D in a WinForms app - the performance is fine for a large graph. It's just rendering GDI, so